# Does Android API have something like Flash's duplicate movieclip?

Tags: android, flash, view

I used to do alot of Flash Actionscript and now I am getting into Android. Is there something in the Android API that is similar to duplicateMovieClip() in Actionscript? I'm sure there is probably a way to write such a method, but I am wondering if there are any existing shortcuts.

For example, say I have an ImageView, TextView, or other kind of View Object on screen and I want to have a button to click which will make a duplicate of some object on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind my asking, *why* do you need something like `duplicateMovieClip()`?

To answer the question, Android doesn't have a notion of the AS2 `duplicateMovieClip()`.  Much like in AS3 (which also didn't have `duplicateMovieClip()`) you'll have to implement your own cloning method.  Java does have an unimplemented '.clone()' method as part of every Java object, so if there's a particular View you would like to clone you might be able to implement your cloning there by 
Overriding the clone method.

I think what you'd probably end up doing instead is doing something more akin to instantiating  from the Library by making small view layouts in xml and inflating them using the Inflater tools.

```
View result = null;

// where pContext is a context object, either supplied by the application
// or just by the current Activity (if available)

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) pContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// where id is the layout id such as R.layout.myclonableview.
// where pRoot is the parent container for the new result.
// where pAttachToRoot is whether to immediately inflate the new view into the root.
result = inflater.inflate(id, pRoot, pAttachToRoot);

// Now "clone" your old view by copying relevant fields from the old one to the
// one stored in result
```

Comment: Yes, it has been awhile since I used flash so am not surprised I'm asking about a depreciated method. ok, so it sounds like the above code is dynamically creating inflating some view object from xml code. And it doesn't matter that the view object has already been instantiated on screen, so this would create a somewhat independent copy, which I can color differently and scale differently, etc?

Comment: That's right, it is a totally new view instance and you can set its properties independently.  The .xml file referenced by R.layout.foo is a pre-defined layout / view that can be thought of similarly to a MovieClip in the Library.  That said, it might be good to know *why* you want to do this, since your problem might be more general and there may be some other pieces of the puzzle to account for.

Comment: There isn't any particular reason why except for just experimenting with android coding trying to learn. I can imaging something like this being useful, for example, in a game where the player clicks a button to get a new ball to launch at a target. But maybe there is a better way to go about doing something like that than inflating a new instance of some ball.xml or ball.png.

Comment: Ah, for most games you'll be best off if you don't rely on the view hierarchy.  It is poorly suited to your needs, both from a performance perspective, as well as an ease-of-use perspective.  Instead you'll want to look into game libraries that render composite bitmaps to a single SurfaceView.  There are many options available.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the info! I'll have to look into that.